# Corner shape of modal view on iPad in ios: Square or rounded?

Tags: ios, ipad, ios8, modal-dialog, modalviewcontroller

Is there a recommended corner style for modal views (not popups) on iOS? Is a square style or a rounded style preferred? Does this recommendation differ across iOS versions?

I can't see any official recommendation by Apple in their user interface guidelines. The App Store app modal popup for viewing an app on iPad has square corners on iOS8. Twitter for iPad iOS8, for example, has a modal popup that has rounded corners.